# Visual Studio, .NET framework v4.5 not found

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the example for AncestralTrees working [here](https://github.com/fire-eggs/Ancestral-Tree). I cloned the repo and try to build, but I get a set of errors that do not make sense.

First is that the .NET framework v4.5 wasn't found. For this I am a bit confused, because I thought it was backwards compatible, and I have v6.0.301 installed. To try and fix this error, I went to the website provided and downloaded it, but it wouldn't install as I already have a newer version. Again, am I missing something?

[image]

Second is that AppSettings.cs and MruStripMenu.cs could not be found. Are these default config files I have to provide, or am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the compatibility issue, .Net Core (6.0) and .Net Framework (4.5) are different animals, with .Net Core as more of a successor to Framework. They are very similar, *but there are some breaking changes between Framework and Core*, and if a project was intended for .Net Framework 4.5 you will want to have it installed on your system and set as the build target for the project in Visual Studio. You could probably also build for 4.7 or 4.8.

For the files, if they are part of the repo I would expect them to be there. I'd check your file system and see if the files are there, and then check the repo on github and see if they are included in the repo. If not, you may need an additional repo or you may need to manually add a NuGet package.

I did notice this at the bottom of the github page:

> This program is both a demo of my GEDCOM library: YAGP, and a hopefully useful program in itself.

Where the "YAGP" text is a dead link. So I would expect to also need this project, which either no longer exists or is not public. This is probably the correct address:

> https://github.com/fire-eggs/YAGP

*(I submitted a change with the fixed link.)*

Comment: By cloning YAGP, downloading the .NET framework and updating the project to work with it, I was able to get past the initial errors! More showed up but I think I am on the right path now! Thanks